# keras loss and other custom mertic not being accurate

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, word-embedding

I have a standard Bidirectional LSTM model built with keras, nothing fancy, just a stack of layers:

> ================================================================= embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 1697, 300)         9776100
>   _________________________________________________________________ bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 1697, 150)         225600
>   _________________________________________________________________ bidirectional_2 (Bidirection (None, 1697, 60)          43440
>   _________________________________________________________________ bidirectional_3 (Bidirection (None, 1697, 40)          12960
>   _________________________________________________________________ last_blstm (Flatten)         (None, 67880)             0
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 339405

My loss seems to be decreasing normally, but the same doesn't go for

> 11800/13500 [=========================>....] - ETA: 2:16 -loss: 107.6926 - acc: 0.2010
>   12000/13500 [=========================>....] - ETA: 2:00 - loss: 106.0187 - acc: 0.2019
>   12200/13500 [==========================>...] - ETA: 1:44 - loss: 104.4009 - acc: 0.2024
>   12400/13500 [==========================>...] - ETA: 1:28 - loss: 102.8412 - acc: 0.2029
>   12600/13500 [===========================>..] - ETA: 1:12 - loss: 101.3140 - acc: 0.2021 
>   12800/13500 [===========================>..] - ETA: 56s - loss: 99.8337 - acc: 0.2021
>   13000/13500 [===========================>..] - ETA: 40s - loss: 98.4028 - acc: 0.2022
>   13200/13500 [============================>.] - ETA: 24s - loss: 97.0180 - acc: 0.2030 
>   13400/13500 [============================>.] - ETA: 8s - loss: 95.6736 - acc: 0.2031
>   13500/13500 [==============================] - 1141s 85ms/step - loss: 94.9990 - acc: 0.2029 - val_loss: 4.7779 - val_acc: 0.2193

which is kind of strange, my dataset is balanced for each class and i'm not using any custom loss function, my optimizer is a standard SGD (also tried Adam, same results) and my batch size is 200

### EDIT: Never mind this part...

Also, i tried adding custom metrics, the results are even more strange:

```
    print("Epoch: {} end".format(epoch))
    val_predict = np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))
    print("Predictions: ", val_predict)
    val_predict = np.argmax(val_predict, axis=1)
    val_targ = self.validation_data[1]
    val_targ = np.argmax(val_targ, axis=1)

    print("Val data: {}, Val pre: {}, val_targ: {}".format(self.validation_data[0][0:100], val_predict[0:10],
                                                           val_targ[0:10]))
```

I get the following output:

> Predictions:  [[0.1997815  0.19978242 0.20011796 0.19970864
>   0.20060949]
>   [0.19989796 0.20036548 0.19994123 0.19979696 0.19999835]  [0.20089898 0.19889246 0.19993879 0.19909698 0.20117281]  ... 
>   [0.19948816 0.20006524 0.19998378 0.2000029  0.20045996]  [0.1996356 
>   0.19995351 0.19997446 0.20012334 0.20031306]
>   [0.20026998 0.19984405 0.20024066 0.19988723 0.19975808]]
>
> Val pre: [4 1 4 1 2 4 4 4 2 4]

If you look closely at the last line, the softmax should output "0" as the predicted class as opposed to 4, it seems the class "0" generally is being missed.

Any idea what's going on?
Thanks

Comment: You meanWhat is the problem? How many classes do you have? What you want to achieve?

Comment: The problem is that the accuracy is not improving while the loss is, i have 5 classes as you can see in the final layer